# Fix CSS so weird spacing never happens in a justified paragraph

Tags: css, html, media-queries

I am not a front end dev but I have inherited a web page that uses media queries and aspect ratio so the content of the page grows proportionally to the size of the viewport, in this case a browser window.  The problem is there is a paragraph on the page that is justified (flush to the left and right), so at certain sizes, the spacing between words is not aesthetically pleasing to my client.  My question is what is standard practice for this sort of thing?  Could one display the content at fixed sizes depending on the size of the browser window using media queries and min-width/max-width min-height/max-height settings, like so:

```
if the viewport size is < x, render content at fixed size a
else if viewport size is < y, render content at fixed size b
else if viewport size is < z, render content at fixed size c
else render content at fixed size d
```

?

Or?

Comment: ignoring the user-story here, and focusing on your question, yes, using css media queries one can easily achieve font change if required - 99% of the cases, imo, it isn't. could you sketch a replica or an example of your situation in jsfiddle ?

Comment: @Stavm Any markup/code supplied **must** be here within the quesiton, not a jsfiddle.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you all for your responses. i just, at least for now and after many hours of reading and trying various things, solved the problem by simply changing one of the font-size settings just slightly. from 2vw to 1.98vw. although end user is happy, i want / need to understand what i've done. looks like it's time to learn front end work.

```
@media all and (max-aspect-ratio: 100/68){
   ...
   table#main td#mainLeft table#logoMoto{
     width: 30vw;
     height: 66vw;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;   
-->  font-size: 1.98vw;  // was font-size: 2vw;
     vertical-align: top; 
   }
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard practice is to not use justified content which suites well to paper but most times not for screen.

What can you do, now you are here:

```
.content{
  width:80%; /* dynamic value */
  max-width:500px; /* fixed maximum */
  /* center */
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

You need to edit the CSS selector to yours

Now you are mobile ready and with a maximum width you can have the "best" looking for your justified text (how often does it change?). You need to play around with the values to get an appropriate result.

You also can change the Values on larger viewport sizes:

```
@media screen and ( min-width:1024px ) {
  .content{
    width:70%; /* dynamic value */
    max-width:1440px; /* fixed maximum */
  }
}
```

Of course you also can leave out the dynamic values and use only fixed values.